# ffmpeg streaming slow on android

Tags: android, performance, ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming

I am trying to forward HLS stream http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/06/prog_index.m3u8 to streaming server from my Android device.

I am using https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java library to get ffmpeg working in my Android Studio project.

The problem is that when I stream in 720p resolution with ffmpeg from my Android phone the server income rate is max 500kbps on 4G network what is not enough for 720p streaming and also 480p.

I tried to troubleshoot this issue by streaming from the same network but using my PC and the server stream income rate was good - around 1200kbps for 720p streaming.

Is it possible that Android device has too slow hardware for ffmpeg? is there a way to use mentioned library with Android hardware acceleration? Would hardware acceleration with MediaCodec API improve streaming speed?

Here is log from my application:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AtXVGSZVYflZhFwIhg1s1jq_6e7g

Here is CPU usage on my Android device:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtXVGSZVYflZhGFT2akG2tD2uelB

Here is CPU usage on my PC:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtXVGSZVYflZhGIPSwe5GHjHWFCG

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the video is streaming ok, without any stuttering and buffering, but just at a lower quality level? Or do you mean that the video is constantly stuttering and buffering?

Comment: I mean that when I am streaming from PC, server income rate is 1200kbps like I set in my ffmpeg comand. Video quality is good, video playback is smooth and without shuttering. When I am streaming from Android device, server income rate is max 500kbps but in my ffmpeg command I set 1200kbps bitrate. In that case video quality is good but video playback is bad. It is shuttering to much and playback is not smooth. Note that I am using same ffmpeg version, same encoding settings, same network and same source stream in both cases.

Comment: If you save the incoming file does it have the right bitrate and quality and playback ok? If it does then it does sound like your Android device is simply being overrun with the task and not able to create the stream at the rate you want (which your CPU graphs also suggest, but CPU graphs can be hard to interpret).

Comment: Yes, if I save ffmpeg input to a file, quality and playback is good. It seems that I will have to find another solution. Thank you for your opinion.